# 3.5" Internal Card Reader with only USB 3.2Gen2 (10G) connector

Tags: usb, motherboard, microsd

I'm searching for an internal 3.5" SD card reader with USB ports. It should support USB 3.0 speeds (5G and up), but must only use the USB 3.2Gen2 10-gig "A key" motherboard connector.
My motherboard only has one 19-pin 3.2Gen1 5G and one A-Key 3.2Gen2 connector, the first of which is already taken up by USB connectors directly on the case.

It should support:

- Full size SD card
- MicroSD card
- USB-A 3.2Gen1/2
- USB-C 3.2Gen1/2

Comment: Do you have a spare PCI-e slot? The most straightforward solution I see is to add another USB header, and the cheapest/best way to do that is with another USB card.

Comment: I've considered that. There's a few that have additional internal headers (e.g. a second 19-pin) and I could use some more rear-facing USB anyways.

Answer (score 0):

## [EZDIY-FAB 3.5" Card Reader](https://ezdiy-fab.com/products/3-5in-pc-front-panel-internal-card-reader-usb-hub-usb-3-1-gen2-type-c-port-usb-3-0?variant=39566215020595&currency=USD) - [$33](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZHBT4S6)

[image]

I'm pretty sure you've seen this reader already, but it's still the best option I see; the 3.5" internal bay market is pretty small these days given that fewer and fewer cases support them. *You will need an additional USB 3.0 header (5 Gbps, 19-pin).* While you could use an internal USB 3.0 hub, these can be expensive and require bandwidth sharing; I'd instead recommend a simple PCI-e card with an internal USB header. These are [readily available from many vendors for about $17.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DFLXVJL)